# List<Tuple<T>> | AddRange with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections, tuples

Im wondering about how to add arrays to a `List<Tuple<double, double>>`.

**My (short) code:**

```
double[] var1 = new double[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
double[] var2 = new double[5] { 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 1.2, 1.1 };

List<Tuple<double, double>> tup = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
```

I would like to fill `tup` with my arrays. Unfortunately for that I would need to instanciate a `Tuple` for each entry. Dont know how to do this.

In general I could just use a loop, but this looks dirty for me. My question is about performance and clean code.

```
if(var1.Length == var2.Length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < var1.Length; i++)
    {
        tup.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(var1[i], var2[i]));
    }
}
```

Isnt there a shorter way to archive this? Any way with `AddRange` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method. Per the docs, this:

> Applies a specified function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, producing a sequence of the results.

In this case, we can use `Tuple.Create` as the function to create a tuple from both elements.

```
var tup = var1.Zip(var2, Tuple.Create).ToList();
```

Though note that this could give a slightly different result to your code in the case where the sequences are not the same length.  Per the docs again:

> If the input sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method combines elements until it reaches the end of one of the sequences

Check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2wu9Et) for a working demo.

Comment: Working well. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* use `Zip` to project the collections to a list of tuples:

```
var tup = var1.Zip(var2, (v1, v2) => new Tuple<double, double>(v1,v2))
              .ToList();
```

But personally I find your original method easier to read and to understand the *intent*.  There should be very little performance difference.  *Shorter* code isn't always *better* code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop yourself or let LINQ loop, `Enumerable.Zip` joins by index:

```
 List<Tuple<double, double>> tup = var1.Zip(var2, (d1, d2) => Tuple.Create(d1, d2))
    .ToList();
```

So this isn't more efficient but might be more readable.